# Disable Update Links Prompt Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that links to a network folder that has the data the file requires.  But I don't want the users to get the question "do you want to update the links?", because it will be updated regardless every time the file is opened with the code below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'assures current data is always used.
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources

End Sub
```

Is there a way to disable the prompt from ever appearing for anyone that uses the file?  I know I can disable it from prompting on my computer, but to make it easier on the user, I don't want them to worry about it.

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

should do the trick.